# Does Python Have a Wildcard Similar to PowerShell?

Tags: python, powershell, email, wildcard

I'm currently working on an email inbox automation project, and I'm trying to use a wildcard to find certain email subjects. The emails sometimes have randomly generated ticket numbers, so I need to compensate for that. Here is how I'd write it in PowerShell.

```
if($email.'Subject' -like 'Test Number:*') {...}
```

This would trigger for each email with the subject line `Test Number:`, regardless of the randomly generated number following.

From what I'm seeing, Python does not simply have a wildcard like PowerShell has `-like` and `*`. That or I'm dumb and can't find it. The only thing I'm seeing involves installing modules to get a wildcard to work. Does Python have a built in wildcard?

Comment: In python, you can write if substring in string. For example if 'Test Number:' in your_email_subject_line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `startswith` in your case

```
email_subjects = ['Test:1', 'Test:25', 'not_valid!']
for email_subject in email_subjects:
    if email_subject.startswith('Test:'):
        print('valid email subjet', email_subject)
    else:
        print('invalid email subjet', email_subject)
```

For the note :

- substring* is equivalent to `string.startsWith(substring)`
- *substring is equivalent to `string.endswith(substring)`
- *substring* is equivalent to `substring in string`

If you have some more complex patterns, I suggest you to use the `re` module. For instance you want to match every: `'Test:X` with X a number between `1` and `25`

```
import re

email_subjects = ['Test:1', 'Test:25', 'not_valid!', 'Test:52']
for email_subject in email_subjects:
    if re.search(''^Test:([0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])$'', email_subject): # Compiles to a regular expression and looks for it in email_subject
        print('valid email subjet', email_subject)
    else:
        print('invalid email subjet', email_subject)
```

Regex breakdown:

- `^` Starting character match
- `Test:` Your string you want to match
- `([0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])`: your range, which means: a number from 0 to 9, or a 1 and a number from 0 to 9 (which means between 10 and 19) or 2 and a number from 0 to 5 (which means between 20 and 25)
- `$` Ending character

Comment: The last part is highly confusing. As in your code, it needs to be `".*"` for a match with any number of any symbol in the regex case. And claiming that the regex `"<pattern>.*"` is equivalent to `string.startsWith(pattern)` is not correct. When using `re` `pattern` is compiled as a regular expression, whereas `startswith` looks for an exact match with the `pattern` string

Comment: Mmmhhh, I see your point, I will rephrase that ! Thanks for pointing out

Comment: In your first example when you have `['Test:1', 'Test:25', 'not_valid!']`, are the numbers the range this would trigger? Like would it only catch emails w/ numbers 1-25?

Comment: @JK72 This does not check what is after 'Test:', but the regex can, I will update the regex !

Comment: @JK72 Updated !